# Point Pair invariants

Tags: modular-forms, automorphic-forms, modular-function

I have been reading Iwaniec's spectral theory of Automorphic forms, and in one of its definition, its defined that a function $k: \mathbb{H}× \mathbb{H} \rightarrow C$ is point pair invariant if $k(gz,gw)=k(z,w)$ for all $g \in G=SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$. But I am not understanding how we can set $k(z,w)=k(u(z,w))$ where k(u) is a function of one variable with $u≥0$ here u is distance function on upper half plane.
I can understand that if you give me a function f from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is even then then $f(u(z,w))$ will give me point pair invariant but how to say converse that is if k is point pair invariant then $k(z,w)=k(u(z,w))$.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: First, you might want to make your question self-contained (e.g., what is G?).  Second, the point is that if k is point point pair invariant, then it only depends on the distance between the points.  Basically you should use that G acts transitively on pairs of points of a given distance d.

Comment: @Kimball Sorry I haven’t included the details, I have now edited that G is $SL_2(\mathbb{R}$. Suppose for a given real number $d  \geq 0$ let S be the set of all points such that their hyperbolic distance is d, then we have action of G on S by $(z,w) \rightarrow (g.z,g.w)$ for g $\in $ G. I am not following that how this action is transitive, because to show its transitive for (z,w) and (z’,w’) in S , i need to find g in G such that (gz,gw)=(z’,w’). Since G acts on upper half plane transitively we have some g in G such that gz=z’, but how does this guarantee gw=w’

Comment: @Kimball  Sir requesting you to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that if $k$ is point point pair invariant, then it only depends on the distance between the points. Basically you should use that $G$ acts transitively on pairs of points of a given distance $d$.  You need to know some basic facts about the action of $G$ on the upper half plane.  Here is a rough geometric sketch.  Let $(z,w)$ and $(z',w')$ be pairs of points in $\mathbb H$, where $z$ and $w$ are distance $d$ apart, and similarly for $z', w'$.

First, how can you prove transitivity on $\mathbb H$?  I don't know what Iwaniec does, but one way is to draw a geodesic from $z$ to $z'$ and then flow along this geodesic.  So you can send $z$ to $z'$ and $w$ goes to some point $w''$ on a circle of radius $d$ about $z'$.  Now use the fact that $G$ contains SO(2) (and conjugates), to show that you can rotate about $z'$ to move $w''$ to $w'$.

Comment: Thanks Sir ! Got it now.